# module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'OAuthHandler'

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, tweepy

So I'm trying to set up Tweepy so I can start programming with it.

How my first program looks:

```
#IMPORTING LIBRARIES
#    * tweepy - Twitter API

import tweepy


#LISTING CREDENTIALS

_consumer_key = 'MYCONSUMERKEY'
_consumer_secret = 'MYCONSUMERSECRETKEY'
_access_token = 'MYACCESSTOKEN'
_access_token_secret = 'MYACCESSTOKENSECRET'


#OAUTHHANDLER INSTANCE
#   * works over HTTP and authorizes devices, APIs, servers, and
#     applications — is a standard that provides secure and delegated access.

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(_consumer_key, _consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(_access_token, _access_token_secret)
auth.secure = True
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#UPDATE STATUS

tweet = "Hello, world!"
api.update_status(status=tweet)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(_consumer_key, _consumer_secret)
AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'OAuthHandler'
```

I feel it could be because of my file structure, but I have played around with moving files around with no luck.

Comment: Quick check: did you call one of your files `tweepy.py`? If so, don't do that.

Comment: I haven't called any of my files tweepy.py

Comment: try `import tweepy` and `print(tweepy.__file__)` and you will see what file was imported - maybe it uses different file than you expect.

Comment: File I'd expect. I'm creating this project in the same place as the tweepy package is. Is this the correct place? Also, it seems there is another folder within tweepy with the same name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try import like this:

```
from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler
auth = OAuthHandler(_consumer_key, _consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(_access_token, _access_token_secret)
```

Hope, it will help :)